# Microsoft C deviation from standard

Tags: c, gcc, visual-studio-2013, undefined-behavior, sequence-points

Any reason for the following aberration?

Consider the following C program (named PstFixInc.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv [])
{
  int num = 0;
  num = (num++) % 4;
  printf ("num: %d\n",num);
  return 0;
}
```

If compiled with `gcc 4.8.1`:

> gcc -o PstFix.exe PstFixInc.c

and then executed, you get the result:

> num: 0

If compiled with Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.21005.1 for x86

> cl PstFixInc.c

and then executed, you get the result:

> num: 1

Comment: its depends on compiler!

Comment: `num = (num++) % 4;` has undefined behavior.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4176333/12711

Comment: This is asked quite often - look up "sequence points" for more info. Basically, no, both compilers are right, and yes, your code is broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is undefined behavior, you are modifying `num` and using its previous value other than to determine the value to be stored within the same sequence point. This is covered in the draft C99 standard section `6.5` paragraph 2 which says:

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an
>   expression.72) Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to
>   determine the value to be stored.73)

There are also two examples of undefined behavior:

```
i = ++i + 1;
a[i++] = i;
```

The first one is pretty similar to your example.
Using `clang` even gives you a nice warning:

```
 warning: multiple unsequenced modifications to 'num' [-Wunsequenced]
  num = (num++) % 4;
  ~     ^
```

Comment: It seems that improved diagnostics that directly reference the source code is one of the primary benefits of clang (vs. GCC).

Answer (score 4):

## This is undefined behavior.

You're assigning to the same variable twice without an interleaving [sequence point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4176333/12711).

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
num = (num++) % 4;
```

is undefined behavior per the C standard. Any result that the code produces is "correct".